# Dos for /f loop adding extra space while parsing reg query

Tags: batch-file, registry

I am putting together a batch file to set JAVA_HOME from a list of currently installed JREs. It then will set the path adding the bin directory.

It pareses, let's me pick, but I see there is an extra space after %JAVA_HOME%. So the path ends up being wrong.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::Script to set JRE or JDK Home. 
@set KeyName=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Development Kit
::@set KeyName=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\JavaSoft\Java Runtime Environment
@set x=0
:: Query with sub-dirs (/s) in regisry 'tree'
:: 
@set Cmd=reg query "%KeyName%" /s

:: Loop against text string 
::for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do set JAVA_HOME=%%j

echo Pick the JRE
for /f "tokens=2*" %%i in ('%Cmd% ^| find "JavaHome"') do (set /a "x+=1" & set JHOME[!x!]=%%j & @echo !x! %%j)

set /p y=
@echo You picked: %y%

@set JAVA_HOME=!JHOME[%y%]!
@set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\BIN;%PATH%
@echo Java Home set to:
@echo %JAVA_HOME%isthis
@echo Path Set to:
@echo %PATH%
```

When run it gets the following. Notice the space between "_101" and "thisis". There is also a space before the \BIN on in the path. 
Am I inadvertently adding a space somehow?
Thanks!
J
    c:\mydir\SetJDK.bat

```
Pick the JRE
1 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
2 C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101
2
You picked: 2
Java Home set to:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 isthis
Path Set to:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101 \BIN;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;
```

Comment: The space is being added where you have `set JHOME[!x!]=%%j &...`.  You should quote the variable=value pair, like `set "JHOME[!x!]=%%j" &...`.  For what it's worth, modern JRE versions symlink the current version within `C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath`.  If you add that directory to your `%PATH%` you might not need the batch script at all.

Comment: Thanks @rojo! Your solution worked! Appreciate the symlink tip.Solaris does the same type of thing. I'm testing Java Deployment Rulesets for various older Oracle Apps on a variety of JRE/JDK combos. I wanted a quick way to "source" different JRE/JDK Homes. I thought about modifying the link, but decided to go for the REG approach.

Answer (score 0):

The extra space is coming from the space before the ampersand. It is included in the SET operation.

You can fix it by removing that space.

```
do (set /a "x+=1"& set JHOME[!x!]=%%j& @echo !x! %%j)
```

Comment: Thanks @soja! Your solution worked as well! I upped your answer, but I'm but a noob here, so you'll have to wait I guess. Once I get this cleaned up a bit and listing both JDK and JRE choices. I'l post it as an answer. Maybe others would find it useful? I sure got tired running a bunch of setup batch files.